# STD::Vector- write directly to the internal array

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

Is the following code ok?:

```
std::vector<char> var;
size_t requiredSize;

getenv_s(&requiredSize, NULL, 0, "Something");
if (requiredSize == 0)
{
   return ENV_NOT_EXIST;
}
if(var.size() < requiredSize)
    var.resize(requiredSize);

// Get the value of the environment variable.
getenv_s(&requiredSize, &var[0], requiredSize, "Something");

std::string str(var.begin(),var.end());
```

If this code is OK, can someone please explain me how the `begin()` and the `end()` values of the `var` vector are updated? it looks like this code changes directly the internal array of the vector, not over the `std::vector` api - so how these values are updated to the actual size?

Comment: Besides the fact that your `std::vector` magically changes its name from `var` to `svar` to `var` again, yes that's save to do.

Comment: In C++11 (and in practice also in C++03) you can do basically the same on std::string, no need for a temporary copy on a vector.

Comment: This is an old one, but I happened across it and looks like somehow no one really answered the initial question of "how the begin() and end() values are updated". It's hiding in plain sight - it's the resize() call.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::vector` guarantees data to be stored contiguously, so writing to data, as long as you do not overrun the end is perfectly fine:

From the C++11 standard section 23.3.6.1.1:

> The elements of a vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if v is
>   a vector where T is some type other than bool, then it
>   obeys the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size().

However, note that resizing the vector might move the data and invalidate iterators.

Unfortunately, the standard does not require `std::vector<T>::iterator` to be a raw pointer type (although it usually is). So, you cannot portably use `std::vector<T>::begin()` to access the first element. There is `std::vector<T>::data()`, which returns a pointer to the first element and which can be used for code that expects raw c-arrays.

I suggest to rewrite your call like this:

```
getenv_s(&requiredSize, var.data(), var.size(), "Something");
if (requiredSize < var.size())
  var.resize(requiredSize);
```

Comment: Before C++03-TC1, the standard guaranteed that data was stored linearly, but not contiguously -- vectors could potentially be padded, and &v.begin()[i] wasn't necessarily the i'th element. In practice, though, all library implementations made this okay.

Comment: assuming I will use std::vector<char>::data(), how the std::vector aware to the getenv_s changes. lets say getenv_s function failes - it starts to change the &var[0] array, but somehow fails in the middle - how does the vectore.end() know untill when the internal array is changed?

Comment: @RRR: Well, you cannot use the `data()` member function, because the pointer it returns is `const` so you cannot write to it (see const-correctness). You can, however just pass `&vec[0]` as you are doing now, due to the guarantees of (recent) C++ standards regarding the storage of a `vector`. Regarding "becoming aware": The function `getenv_s` just writes to the buffer and the data is there. The vector doesn't need to become "aware" of anything.

Comment: @bitmask: There are both `const` and non-`const` overloads of `vector::data()` (at least in C++11, but I'm fairly sure that's not new). Perhaps you're thinking of `std::string`?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Oh boy, I must be blind, I specifically checked my statement by looking at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) but some neuron decided not to see the first overload. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @RRR: Please see my edit! My statement about `std::vector<T>::data()` war wrong. Please use `var.data()` instead of `&var[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old one, but I happened across it and looks like somehow no one really answered the initial question of "how the begin() and end() values are updated" when the vector's internal array is manipulated directly. The answer is hiding in plain sight - it's the resize() call.